# Why clicking on sidebar links takes to raw content page on github wiki?

Tags: github

I have created a github `Wiki` page `Introduction.md` and sidebar file `_Sidebar.md` in the same directory in a private repo. When I click on sidebar link I'm redirected to raw page, although the link shows appropriate url.

page `Introduction.md` has below content

```
# Introduction <a name="heading--1">

This is a web application.
```

And the `_Sidebar.md` has below content:

```
# Table of contents

**[1. Introduction](Introduction.md#heading--1)**
```

On hovering the link on sidebar it shows correct url as:
`https://github.com/testorg/ecom/wiki/Introduction.md#heading--1`

But on clicking the link it redirects to raw page and shows the raw content for `Introduction.md` above
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/testorg/ecom/Introduction.md?token=GHSAT0AAAAAATESTINGTOKENAZG2ZMAQ33POCYYHFSBQ#heading--1`

Why this type of behavior, What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, however, is one small issue in your URL. Instead of

```
**[1. Introduction](Introduction.md#heading--1)**
```

Remove .md from the URL.

```
**[1. Introduction](Introduction#heading--1)**
```